# Spring Boot Security 4 with ZooKeeper - Security integration issue

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-netflix

The spring application was integrated with ZooKeeper using spring cloud bridge.  It was working without security corectly.
I have used default security configuration (*spring-boot-sample-web-secure*) in my application (planing to customize if default conf will be working.). At first time I've got error **Expected CSRF token not found** - removed CSRF filter from my *event bus*

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/inner/service/event/bus").csrf().disable().anonymous()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
  }
}
```

but because of inner services via Zookeeper I've got other problem

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: publishEvent timed-out and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:801)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:785)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:139)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1514)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1404)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:141)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:951)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:971)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:596)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:577)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:139)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas how it can be fixed or what i need to investigate to get ideas for solution?

Comment: if someone needs more details, just let me know please

Comment: Consider https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/discovery/ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration.java. I would start with the following: 1) permit url used in IPing; 2)

Comment: 2) set Feign logger to Logger.Level.FULL (check https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignAutoConfiguration.java to find a necessary bean) so you could see all discovery ping/health requests and responses.

Comment: Seems problem disapeared. I did not understand reason of problem, possible configuration or shared zookeeper server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Spring Discovery uses application health/ping urls for heart-beating, it makes sense to start with permitting all except your business services.

For a further fine-tuning I would recommend setting RibbonClient (used by Spring Discovery as an HTTP transport) to Logger.Level.FULL, getting all interactions and then permitting them.

Also you can provide all discovery interactions with some request header, which should be recognisable and allowable by Spring Security.